# Generate scripts SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, scripting

I would like to generate scripts of about 100 Stored Procedures. When I generate script, all the files contains 'CREATE PROCEDURE' statement. How should I get scripts with 'ALTER PROCEDURE' statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate all the scripts to a new query window you could press Ctrl-Shift-H to get the find and replace in files dialog up and do a finf and replace on 'CREATE PROCEDURE' to 'ALTER PROCEDURE'?

Answer (score 2):

- Find/replace in an editor
- Script with a DROP first
- Use a 3rd party to generate a differential script instead